# How do I include css files outside static folder?

Tags: css, node.js, html, express, semantic-ui

I was trying to include semantic_ui css files from folder semantic in home.html which reside in public folder. its was loading fine without server but express is not serving any .css file outside static folder. I don't want to move my files

home.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../semantic/out/semantic.css">
```

my directory structure

```
root-folder
    node_modules
    ...
    semantic
        out
            semantic.css
            semantic.js
        src
           ...
        tasks
           ...
        gulpfile.js
    public (static folder)
        home.html
    app.js
```

Comment: href="../sementic/out/semantic.css" => typo?

Comment: no, it was in the question only. question edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express allows to use multiple static directories. From the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html),

To use multiple static assets directories, call the express.static middleware function multiple times:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('semantic'))
```

Express looks up the files in the order in which you set the static directories with the express.static middleware function.